# C or C++ to write a compiler?

Tags: c++, c, comparison, compiler-theory

I want to write a compiler for a custom markup language, I want to get optimum performance and I also want to have a good scalable design.

Multi-paradigm programming language (C++) is more suitable to implement modern [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29), but I think that will degrade performance a little bit (think of [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) for example) which more or less might make C a better choice.

I wonder what is the best language (C, C++ or even objective C) if someone wants to create a modern compiler (in the sense of complying to modern software engineering principles as a software) that is fast, efficient, and well designed.

Comment: RTTI is only a performance hit if you use it. Write it in the language you're most comfortable with, and if it turns out to be too slow in some area, optimize that part.

Comment: Use [LOLCode](http://www.lolcode.com). :)

Comment: Think of C++ as "a better C".  I think you're on safe ground with it.  Bjarne designed the language with "only pay for what you use" in mind.

Comment: C++ is a much better language for modelling complex problems *if* you know how to use it well. If you have to ask a question like this, you obviously don't. The answer hinges more on your ability to understand the implications of choices in C++ - there's nothing inherent in C++ that will make it slower than C.

Comment: Clang is written in C++ and has a good, scalable design. GCC is written in C and I still have nightmares from the last time I looked at the source code.

Comment: The nightmares in the GCC C code are less to do with what it was written in and more to do with who it was written by.

Comment: You don't need to use "expensive" parts of C++ to take advantage of many of its most useful features.

Comment: Some of the good design pattern (like factory method and template method) are built upon OO idioms, implementing them (which is considered a good practice in engineering software) requires using the costly OO power of C++, the question is, to what extent? if we are considering a fast and efficient product.

Comment: @H.Josef: The 'costly OO power of C++' usually has the same cost for the same thing in C: if you want to implement structures with vtables, it'll cost you much the same.  C strongly *discourages* you from doing it because it's not at all easy to do.  Arguably, it trains you to avoid OO design patterns, and the patterns you fall back on happen to be more efficient (and perhaps less maintainable as a trade-off, though as with any other language you'll find C code poetry and C++ monstrosities).

Comment: @ijw, I think the conclusion is the trade-off between maintainability (through OO design patterns) and slightly-better performance (through handmade patterns using C) is the question. thanks

Comment: @H.Josef: Just to add my 5 cents. You can also control most of the C++ features. If you don't want to support exceptions in your code, you can simply turn them off (compiler switch). The same applies to RTTI. But C++ gives you much more power and additionaly controlling features. Most of them rely on static typing. Just 3 weeks ago I had to work with some legacy C code and was really lucky that I can now program C++. In most cases where C++ would produce errors, C produced warning, which were easily to oversee if compiled from command line.

Comment: @dreamlax, @ijw: GCC is a great example of how complex things get when you try and implement OO using the functionality of C. Basically the Whole tree concept and associated macros is an attempt at a class hierarchy with methods (written in C). Very confusing hard to maintain but ultimately it shows it can be done.

Comment: @Martin York: No, gcc is just badly executed.  It's perfectly possible to apply OO concepts to C in a reasonable way although you have to do vtables manually - not that I would choose to write a compiler in C if I have C++ available.

Comment: (+1) Because it mentions "C++" multiparadigm, not just Object and Class Oriented...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "expensive" features of C++ (e.g., exceptions, virtual functions, RTTI) simply don't exist in C. By the time you simulate them in C, you're likely to end up with something at least as expensive as it is in C++, but less known, less documented, etc. (let's face it: compiler writers aren't stupid -- while it's *possible* you can implement a feature "better" than them, it's not really particularly likely).

In the other direction, templates (for one example) often make it relatively easy to write code that is considerably *faster* than is practical in C. Just for one obvious example, C++ code using `std::sort` will often be two to three times as fast as equivalent C code using `qsort`.

Bottom line: the only reason for a C++ program to be slower than an equivalent written in C is if you've decided (for whatever reason) to write slower code. Common reasons are simplicity and readability -- and in most cases, those *are* more important than execution speed. Nonetheless, using C++ doesn't necessarily carry any speed penalty. It's completely up to you to decide whether to do something that might run more slowly.

Comment: Great comment, in first paragraph you just explained what design patterns are all about. I think you are right, because when creating a complex system we will often come up with patterns that are already there. What makes me still in doubt, some companies like Apple, still prefer using objective C instead of C++, and I think the reason is performance. Are RTTI, and vtables really that costly?

Comment: I don't believe Objective C has a performance advantage over C++. Actually, rather the contrary, where the two have equivalent/congruent features, the C++ version typically has better performance. Apple's preference seems to be based on a large investment in their current code base, not performance.

Comment: I would very much doubt that the choice of Objective-C over C++ is one of performance.  Every call in Objective-C goes through this message dispatcher thing, that searches the entire object to see if something should be called.  It's quite slow in comparison to vtables but is also much less strict and a little more like OO puritains like.  The API is also quite nice and there really are a lot of cool things that are easy with ObjC that are harder in C++.

Comment: The reason `std::sort` can outperform `qsort`, as it's been explained to me, is that the extra type information provided by the template system makes it possible/easier to inline comparisons.

Comment: @Karl: It's not just type information, but yes, inlining comparison code is the single largest factor in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

C++ adheres to a "pay only for what you use" policy.  You are not going to see performance hits due to the language choice; the performance of your application will be purely dependent upon your implementation.

Comment: In theory. In practice, if you decide for example that `iostreams` are too slow for your need (and this does happen), then you start writing `printf` everywhere. Keep doing this with a few features and before you know it, although you're writing C++, it's non-idiomatic to the point of almost becoming a C/C++ mash-up. And nobody wants that.

Comment: @Tomalak: No, no, you don't. printf is a library, not a language feature. C can never replace C++'s language features.

Comment: @DeadMG `printf` is _in_ a library. It's in the C standard library, and in the C++ standard library. Though I understand what you're saying, I was talking about the language plus library as a whole, as defined by the standard and as what we call in totality "idiomatic C++". My point was that writing with the C++ language but restricting to the subset of the C++ library that was inherited from C is considered to be non-idiomatic.

Comment: @Tomalak: Of course. But then, IOstreams are pretty much the *only* part of the C++ Standard library that has a single reason to go back to C's way of doing things. Nobody cares about the C subset of the C++ Standard lib, because nobody uses it, except a *very* few specific functions, like say _alloca().

Comment: Idiomatic or not, you still get the benefits of C++ and no mandatory performance penalty.

Comment: @DeadMG: Agreed. I thought I could think of a few more on top of iostreams, but I'm struggling.

Comment: @EdSwangren: Performance is not only measured in build and run times but also in maintainability and elegance of code. :) OK, so I made that up, but those are also important considerations.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, I don't think that is actually a measure of performance :D.  Still though, maintainability has nothing to do with C or C++.  One can write great, maintainable code in either language.

Comment: @EdSwangren: I disagee that non-idiomatic C++ is particularly maintainable, especially when bringing development colleagues into the mix. That's what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered OCaml? Functional languages are well-suited for compiler writing. Pattern matching is an extremely useful construct, and the lack of side effects will make parallelization easy.

OCaml can be compiled to native code, and its performance is comparable to C and C++. Its standard library is somewhat lacking, but you don't really much else to write a compiler.

F# is a very similar language if you prefer a .NET environment.

Comment: No, I am not aware of OCaml, I will take a look at it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

People who write compilers in C as their basic language usually have the good sense to use tools for certain parts of it.

Specifically, go find out about lex and yacc (in their free implementations, [flex](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)).

This advice almost certainly applies to any other language you choose, be it C++, Java or whatever.

Comment: Java: JavaCup+JFlex, C++: Re-flex&|re2 + bison, C: flex+bison. Also LLVM. I've written several compilers.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have any links but from what i hear and from experience C/C++ is a poor language to write a compiler with. First of all, do you really honestly need it to be scalable? Or scalable at this stage? Especially for a markup language? your not compiling 60+ mb of source so i dont think you actually need it to be scalable.

Anyways for my programming language i used bison for the parser (reading bison+flex is a must, try to avoid all conflicts my language has none). Then i use both C and C++ for the code. C because bison uses C and i just call a simple C function which creates and fill in a struct to create an abstract syntax tree. Then when its done it calls my C++ code that runs through the AST and generate the binary.

Standard ML is suppose to be really good with creating a language. If you dont use that a functional language is a good choice because it fits with the mindset (parsing may be left to right but your function calls wont be in that order). So i recommend that if you dont use bison (or know how to call it using C/C++ and bison).

Note: I tried writing a compiler twice. The first time in C without bison the 2nd time with bison. Theres no question that it would have taken me exponentially longer due to the fact that bison finds the conflicts for me and i am not doomed in debug land (i would probably in fact try to figure out a way to report conflicts before i write the code which is exactly what bison does)

Answer (score 1):

Forget what programming language you use & also given that you have huge memory support in these modern computer era you could write good & fast programs using interpreted language and also very bad & slow running programs using C/C++ (compiled languages) & vice versa.

What is important is to use right data structures and algorithms & follow the style/patterns of the programming language you use to implement it. Remember that some one said "OO is not a panacea" & to the other extent some one else also said "show your data structures and I will code up the algorithm for the problem you are trying to solve".

Comment: programming language itself is very important when considering a product like a compiler since performance is a major factor (think of writing an online XML validation service that might serve thousands of clients concurrently). Getting the best of both (performance and maintainability of software) is what I am seeking